# Unity to Xcode 8.3. Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 _addZipFile", referenced from error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, zip, augmented-reality, arm64

I am developing an AR project in Unity and building an iOS build. From Unity, build is successful but in Xcode build is giving error like this.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
    "_addZipFile", referenced from:
    _ZipUtil_addZipFile_m779653781 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
    _ZipUtil_Zip_m3365174905 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
    (maybe you meant: _ZipUtil_addZipFile_m779653781)
    "_zip", referenced from:
    _ZipUtil_zip_m353699619 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
    _ZipUtil_Zip_m3365174905 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
    (maybe you meant: _ZipUtil_zip_m353699619)
    "_unzip", referenced from:
    _ZipUtil_unzip_m1045744427 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
    (maybe you meant: _ZipUtil_unzip_m1045744427)

    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have already tried all the possible solution searched here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using UnityZip plugin in your project but when your xcode project is built it says that it can find a UnityZip's plugin to link. So all the code which is using this plugin is unknown to compiler. Look at the [UnityZip github page](https://github.com/tsubaki/UnityZip) one more time. I suppose that you've missed this step:

> add file "PluginsCode>iOS>ZipArchive" to xcode project.

So just add needed files to the project and it should compile.

Comment: Thanks, this works, and error was gone. But new error is coming related to Unknown type name 'bool'